# How use addClass and removeClass same anchor and div .. anchor is click addClass and item is addClass active

Tags: jquery, css

How can I use anchor click `addClass` and item `addClass` one to one?

How use jQuery add Class and `removeClass` and JavaScript?

> one anchor active == 1 item active
>
> two anchors active == 2 item active

```
<div class="itemlabel">
    <a href="#select1">1</a>
    <a href="#select2">2</a>
    <a href="#select3">3</a>
    <a href="#select4">4</a>
    <a href="#select5">5</a>
    <a href="#select6">6</a>
    <a href="#select7">7</a>
    <a href="#select8">8</a>                    
</div>

<div class="item active">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select2">2</div>
</div>
<!-- repeat for other items -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".itemlabel a").on("click" ,function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aungnyeinmin/D7wab/

Comment: Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja5r4/1/) what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) to find out which anchor is clicked and use that index to select the corresponding item below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $anchors = $('.itemlabel a'),
    $items = $('.item');

    $anchors.on('click', function() {
        var selectedIndex = $anchors.index(this);

        $anchors.removeClass('active').eq(selectedIndex).addClass('active');
        $items.removeClass('active').eq(selectedIndex).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ja5r4/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".itemlabel a").on("click" ,function(){
            $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            //how use itemdown scroll jquery
            $($($(this).attr('href')).parents('.item')[0]).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/D7wab/3/

Comment: Is it that what you want?